# Finding the shortest path within a 2D matrix

Tags: matrices

I've a task where I need to find the shortest needed to connect multiple nodes in a 2d Matrix and count the steps needed. What I've as an input is

```
oooooooo
...ooooB
ooxoxxxx
Coxooooo
ooxooDoo
oooooooo
ooAooooo
oooooooo
```

Where the `A-D` are the nodes that I need to connect, `o` are the nodes I can traverse on and `x` are the inaccessible nodes. There is also the `.` node, which is already cleared.
The solution here would be and the nodes cleared will be 11.

```
oooooooo
.......B
.ox.xxxx
Cox.oooo
oox..Doo
oo..oooo
ooAooooo
oooooooo
```

What I was able to find, looking at the Dijkstra's algorithm wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), is the variant where a single node is picked as the source and finds the path to all other nodes in the graph(matrix). My question is what is the most optimal solution, especially in the case where there are nodes that are already cleared.

Comment: Have you investigated the notion of a minimal spanning tree? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

Comment: I did, but the thing here is that I need a weighted graph to start with (which is not a problem to create) and after let's say connecting B and C I need to update it, so that now B and D nodes are actually closer and the connection between them has less 'weight'.